# oAuth Implementation for .Net Core API and deploying it in App Service & APIM

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I am trying to implement the OAuth 2.0 in .Net core API.
I have created a simple .Net core 3.1 application that has weatherforecast controller (it is decorated with Authorize Keyword).
I haven't written anything extra as of now, nothing in a startup.cs.
Now I have published this API in the Azure App service.
Now when I hit the URL through postman, I get an 401 Unauthorized error, which is obvious as I didn't provide any token, client id, secret key to that.

Note I am using Auth type as oAuth 2.0 in postman.
So from where will I get this values:
[image]

Also, I am testing this through postman, how do I take the token in code itself validate it and run the application.

Comment: Please look at my screenshot carefully, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has user login, you should use `Authorization code flow`, if you still want use Client Credentials flow, you also can refer links I provided .

For more details, please check below pic.

[image]

> how do I take the token in code itself validate it and run the application.

This question, you can refer this official document.

[Verify scopes in APIs called on behalf of users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles#verify-scopes-in-apis-called-on-behalf-of-users)

## Steps:

**App registrations**

[1. Client Side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-app-registration#add-client-credentials-by-using-the-azure-portal)

[2. Server Side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration)

*Scope format like below:*

*Official doc*:  [Exposed API--Application ID URI and scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#exposed-api)

```
api://{server-side-clientId}/.default
```

[image]